# how to populate data using NSdictionary?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, nsarray, nsdictionary

How to send data to a table view in another detail view controller ? At my first table I am not getting my expected output. now i need to populate my second table with data which has a property detailContent. here is my code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RecipeBookViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end``
```

\at implementation :

```
#import "RecipeBookViewController.h"
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"

@interface RecipeBookViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecipeBookViewController {
    NSArray *recipes;
}

@synthesize tableView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    recipes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Veg", @"Non Veg", @"Beverages", nil];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.detailContent = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}


@end
```

\detail view :

```
@interface RecipeDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *recipeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *recipeName;
@property (nonatomic , strong)NSString *recipeTable ;
@property (nonatomic , strong) IBOutlet UITableView *detailContent ;


@end
```

at implementation :

```
#import "RecipeDetailViewController.h"

@interface RecipeDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecipeDetailViewController

@synthesize recipeLabel;
@synthesize recipeName;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set the Label text with the selected recipe
    recipeLabel.text = recipeName; 
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Comment: Faisal, what is exactly the problem ? are you able to push the viewController, or the problem that you don't see your data on the next view ?

Comment: i want to populate the second table sir . if am clicking veg in 1st table, then i should see veg list like (chappathi, rotti, etc..) in detail view table. if nonveg (chicken, mutton, etc...) like that. i don't know where and how to declare this one. can you help ?Pls ..it would be more helpful for me as fresher

Comment: So, now you don't see the veg on the next viewController, right ? if the answer is yes, then did your check you outlets ?

Comment: destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        destViewController.detailContent = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  -> you are passing the same string twice to the second VC. Shouldn't one be the NSDictionary with the details? I don't see any NSDictionary anywhere at all...

Comment: @Basheer_CAD : i am seeing the veg label in second controller, i have one table view also there in second table.now i want to fill the table with veg,nonveg and beverage datas  using NSDictionary !

Comment: I've got it, your outlets are strong probably you are not setting them from the interface builder properly, because they should be weak.

Comment: @joao oh sir, i don't know about this one. destViewController.detailContent = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; i can't use this one ? sir , can you explain now how to populate that detail and also how to use this detailContent Property.

Comment: @Basheer_CAD i kept everything as strong only sir.! can you edit my code and give some suggestion ? Pls assist and guide me in this . i didn't declared anything about table data yet in this. have you checked it ?

Comment: If you want to populate your table view with an NSDictionary you need to create it somewhere and/or pass its pointer. In the code you show there is no NSDictionary to be seen. Where is the information you want to be displayed in the second view controller?

Comment: @joao yes sir. right. i created nsdictionary property now in detail view controller as recipeDict. how to use this one and populate the table in detailView. sir. can you Get me what am trying to say? i want to populate the second table sir . if am clicking veg in 1st table, then i should see veg list like (chappathi, rotti, etc..) in detail view table. if nonveg (chicken, mutton, etc...) like that.

Comment: If you already have the nsdictionary you can transform it into an NSArray like [recipeDict values] for the values and [recipeDict keys] for its keys. The next step is exactly like the first case you have.

Comment: @joao this is my NSDictionary Sir. "vegDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Rotti",@"Chappathi", nil]  in detail view;" now how can i pass this data ? and also in my celforRowAtIndexPath ,  i have "cell.textLabel.text = [vegDict objectForKey:vegDict];" . could you give me code to pass this to second table pls?

Answer (score -1):

To populate the next tableView, you need to implement UITableView delegate and protocol methods 
in your RecipeDetailViewController 
Implementation:

```
@interface RecipeDetailViewController () <UItableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation RecipeDetailViewController

@synthesize recipeLabel;
@synthesize recipeName;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Set the Label text with the selected recipe
    recipeLabel.text = recipeName;




}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipes count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

in RecipeDetailViewController.h

```
@interface RecipeDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *recipeLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *recipeName;
@property (nonatomic , strong)NSString *recipeTable ;
@property (nonatomic , strong) IBOutlet UITableView *detailContent ;

// new 
@property(strong) NSArray recipe;
```

@end

Back to RecipeBookViewController.m

```
in PrepareForSegue 

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipe = recipe;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for this help sir. its working.now i need to populate data like chappathi , rotti while clicking veg. and while clicking nonveg some other items like that .. can you say how to declare this one ?

Comment: sir, i have this "vegDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Rotti",@"Chappathi", nil] in detail view;" now how can i pass this data ? and also in my celforRowAtIndexPath , i have "cell.textLabel.text = [vegDict objectForKey:vegDict];" pls explain how to pass the vegDIct to second table

Comment: sir, i have an updated code for this same one. can you help me out for output ?